# Same structure objects memory overlap?

Tags: c

```
struct integer
{
    int len;
    char* str;
    int* arr;
}int1, int2;


int main(void) {
    printf("Please enter 1st number\n");
    int1.str= str_input();
    int1.len=chars_read-1;
    int1.arr= func2(int1.len, int1.str);
    printf(("\%c\n"), *int1.str);
    printf("Please enter 2nd number\n");
    int2.str = str_input();
    int2.len=chars_read-1;
    printf(("\n %c\n"), *int1.str );
    int2.arr= func2(int2.len, int2.str);
```

if the input is 4363 and 78596 , the output is 4 and 7 respectively.

The output is not 4 and 4. Given that both are different objects, shouldn't both have different memory allocation?

Please note: this is NOT a typographical error. I have used the same *int1.str both times. the problem is that although I have made no changes in it, its value is changing. How?
I do not think that str_input() can make a difference.

```
char* str_input(void) {
char cur_char;
char* input_ptr = (char*)malloc(LINE_LEN * sizeof(char));
char input_string[LINE_LEN];
//while ((cur_char = getchar()) != '\n' && cur_char<='9' && cur_char>='0' && chars_read < 10000)
for(chars_read=1; chars_read<10000; chars_read++)
{
    scanf("%c", &cur_char);
    if(cur_char!='\n' && cur_char<='9' && cur_char>='0')
    {
        input_string[chars_read-1]= cur_char;
        printf("%c\n", input_string[chars_read-1]);
    }
    else{
            break;
    }
}
input_string[chars_read] = '\n';
input_ptr = &input_string[0]; /* sets pointer to address of 0th index */
return input_ptr;
}

//chars_read is a global variable.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show `func2` and `str_input` functions.

Comment: `input_ptr = &input_string[0];` you are returning a pointer to an automatic variable. (and leaking memory)

Comment: Learn to format code; it makes a world of difference! Your code here looks bad. And, never use TABs.

Answer (score 2):

you have printed the same variable, `*int1.str`

It will be helpful have the source code of `str_input()`, but it's probably that it returns a pointer to the same buffer in each call, so the second call to `str_input()` updates also the target of `int1.str` (beacuse it's pointing to the same `char*` than `int2.str`)

Answer (score 2):

As noted elsewhere, both of the `printf` calls in your question pass `*int1.str` to `printf`.

However, if that is merely a typographical error in your question, and the second `printf` call passes `*int2.str`, then most likely the problem is that `str_input` returns the address of a fixed buffer (with static or, worse, automatic storage duration). Instead, `str_input` should use `malloc` or `strdup` to allocate new memory for each string and should return a pointer to that. Then the caller should free the memory.

Alternatively, `str_input` may be changed to accept a buffer and size passed to it by the caller, and the caller will have the responsibility of providing a different buffer for each call.

### About the newly posted code

The code for `str_input` contains this line:

```
char* input_ptr = (char*)malloc(LINE_LEN * sizeof(char));
```

That declares `input_ptr` to be a `char *` and calls `malloc` to get space. Then `input_ptr` is set to contain the address of that space. Later, `str_input` contains this line:

```
input_ptr = &input_string[0];
```

That line completely ignores the prior value of `input_ptr` and overwrites it with the address of `input_string[0]`. So the address returned by `malloc` is gone. The `str_input` function returns the address of `input_string[0]` each time it is called.  This is wrong. `str_input` **must** return the address of the allocated space each time.

Typically, a routine like this would use `input_ptr` throughout, doing its work in the `char` array at that address. It would not use a separate array, `input_string`, for its work. So delete the definition of `input_string` and change `str_input` to do all its work in the space pointed to by `input_ptr`.

Also, do not set the size of the buffer to `LINE_LEN` in one place but limit the number of characters in it with `chars_read < 10000`. Use the same limit in all places. Also allow one byte for a null character at the end (unless you are **very** careful never to perform any operation that requires a null byte at the end).

Comment: It's automatic. The code has just been posted. It uses `malloc`, but `input_ptr = &input_string[0];` leaks the allocated memory.

Comment: I do not understand this. How do I prevent this?